# How exec sudo command via Publish Over SSH Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sudo

For example I have this code in my pipeline:

```
sshPublisher(
    failOnError: true,
    continueOnError: false,
    publishers: [
        sshPublisherDesc(
            configName: 'some_config',
            verbose: true,
            transfers: [
                sshTransfer(
                    sourceFiles: 'some_path/some_script.sh',
                    remoteDirectory: '/tmp',
                    removePrefix: 'some_path',
                    execCommand: 'sudo cp /tmp/some_script /usr/local/bin/some_script && sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/some_script'
                )
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

But during execution this code I have error:

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
```

Ssh config `some_config` content username and ssh private key.

How I can exec sudo commands?

If I use `usePty` then the process infinite wait password.